# Textview with a bottom drawing custom line

Tags: android, textview, line, customization, draw

I just wanted to know how doing something like that:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: designing a layout like that or what?

Comment: Hey two ways to do this                                            1)Get the image for the floroscent arc                             2)create an xml for the semi-semi circle and create a view in your layout.xml and give this xml as the background to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `drawableBottom` to your `TextView` like :

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/my_txt"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:drawableBottom="@drawable/my_drawable" />
```

, where `my_drawable` is located in your resource folders and that's the green line which you want under your `TextView`.

Comment: thx! My first Idea was to make it drawing the line but a pics should make it :)

Comment: it will take you more time to draw in instead of just using a png file and attach it to your textview. : )

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `android:drawableBottom="@drawable/YourDrawing"`

like the following..

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="23:00"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/YourDrawing"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```